# How do I install dselect package via terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I was tasked to install the "dselect package" but can't seem to find any "apt-get command thing" on the internet. Only commands which use the dselect command from the Debian docs.

**What I have tried**

```
sudo apt-get install dselect_1.19.0.5Ubuntu2.i386.dev
```

But it can't be found

**NOTE:**

- Since I have an Intel processor I should go for the i386, right?
- I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dselect`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&arch=i386&searchon=names&keywords=dselect) is available for Ubuntu 18.04, you should have the following line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main 
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt updates
sudo apt install dselect
```

[Ubuntu : Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine)

Comment: To get the info from this package? like dpkg --info dselect? Doesn't work. I know its a question inside other but can't seem to find where it i installed now...

Comment: @WhiteGlove `sudo dselect` then Select , hit Space bare , scroll to the desired package,  hit `i` to choose the package then `d` to display the information.

Comment: @WhiteGlove you can get the *description* of the installed package using `dpkg-query -W -f '${Description}\n' dselect` - personally I find it easier to use `apt show dselect` (or `apt-cache show dselect`) which will give information about the package even if not installed